# Regular Expressions Parenthesis AND double quotes

Tags: c#, regex

I have a task to write a C# application to parse an xml file.  One of the attribute values in the file is a Replace statement and I have to parse it to create a PowerShell Replace statement.  I'm using regex to do this.  The string looks like this:

**Replace(FileName, ".txt", ".doc")**

I want to capture "FileName", ".txt" and ".doc"

My question is, how do I match against the open (left) parens AND the double-quotes ?

My issue is, I can't use

```
@"\"pattern\""
```

because the '@' symbol doesn't recognize the escaped double-quotes (in VS 2015).  And if I remove the '@', then how do I escape the opening (left) parens ?  I can't use

```
"\("
```

as an escape sequence b/c the compiler says, "unrecognized escape sequence".

Anyway, all help is appreciated.

Comment: use two back-to-back double quotes when using string literals - `@" double quotes "" "`

Comment: Thank you, that did it. I will remember the back-to-back solution on literals.

Answer (score 2):

The regular expression formatted to be readable:

```
  var pattern =@"
    Replace
    \(
    (?<filename>\w+)
    \,\s*
    \u0022                # double quote
    \.
    (?<txt>\w+)
    \u0022
    ,\s*
    \u0022
    \.
    (?<doc>\w+)
```

";

The unicode \u0022 is the double quote

**The following class parse the text and extract filename , Txt and Doc :**

```
 class RegParser
{
    public string FileNmae { get; set; }
    public string Doc { get; set; }
    public string Txt { get; set; }      




    private static string pattern = @"
    Replace
    \(
    (?<filename>\w+)
    \,\s*
    \u0022                # double quote
    \.
    (?<txt>\w+)
    \u0022
    ,\s*
    \u0022
    \.
    (?<doc>\w+)     
 ";         

    private Regex regex = new Regex(pattern,
           RegexOptions.Singleline
           | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture
           | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant
           | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
           | RegexOptions.Compiled
           );

    public void Parse(string text)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("text: {0}",text);
        Match m = regex.Match(text);
        FileNmae = m.Groups["filename"].ToString();
        Doc = m.Groups["doc"].ToString();
        Txt = m.Groups["txt"].ToString();        
    }
}
```

[Try it](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IDdEi1)

**sample output:**

```
 text: Replace(FileName, ".txt", ".doc")
 FileNmae: FileName
 Doc:  doc
 Txt:    txt
```

Answer (score 1):

A sample regex could look like

```
^Replace\((\w+)\s*,\s*("[^"]*")\s*,\s*("[^"]*")\)$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5EReplace%5C((%5Cw%2B)%5Cs*%2C%5Cs*(%22%5B%5E%22%5D*%22)%5Cs*%2C%5Cs*(%22%5B%5E%22%5D*%22)%5C)%24&i=Replace(FileName%2C%20%22.txt%22%2C%20%22.doc%22))

To define it in C#, you may choose between a *regular string literal* (that supports *escape sequences* like `\n` for a literal newline) where you need to escape the double quote and double escape special regex chars (because a regex engine requires a literal backslash in `\d` or `\.` to match a digit or a dot respectively):

```
var pattern = "^Replace\\((\\w+)\\s*,\\s*(\"[^\"]*\")\\s*,\\s*(\"[^\"]*\")\\)$";
```

or use a *verbatim string literal* (that does not parse escape sequences, `@"\d"` is a string containing 2 chars, `\` and `d`, which matches a digit) to  avoid overescaping with `\`, but you need to double the double quote to insert a literal double quote in the string:

```
var pattern = @"^Replace\((\w+)\s*,\s*(""[^""]*"")\s*,\s*(""[^""]*"")\)$
```

Comment: Also, see [*Strings in C# and .NET*](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx) for some more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 string t = @" name ""test""";
 Console.WriteLine(t);
```

The output is ==> name "test"